# What design pattern would be best to allow one common class from multiple providers?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm looking to write an application. Think e-commerce. But think, an e-commerce site that is powered by another provider.

The scenario would be thus: I would white-label an e-commerce site front that's powered by a client's existing e-commerce platform, whether this be Magento, CubeCart, Prestashop, or so on.

These platforms are all going to have their own naming conventions and whatnot, and I want a common interface within my app. For example:

```
class Product {
    var $title;
    var $price;
    var $image;
    var $description;
    // and so on
}
```

Obviously different providers may call things differently. For example, `title` may be `product_title` in a provider, or `product_name`, or `productTitle`, and so on. Another example: `price` may be `cost`, or `unit_price`, and so on. Hopefully the problem becomes apparent.

Ideally, I'd like to be pointed to the best design pattern to abstract a service from my app's business classes, so I can add providers without having to re-factor anything in my app down the line.

What design pattern would be the best for the above scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd go with something like this:

[image]

Depending on the providers you want to integrate with, you may want to add additional [Decorators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) or [Facades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) (for example to simplify API) between Adapters and actual providers.

Comment: Hi, kstaruch. That's great, and bonus points for the illustration! I'll have a look at integrating the adaptor factory pattern; I was already thinking of going down this route as per my comment on Naved's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think Facade pattern would be better to add Providers with your business classes. However, Adapter pattern will also be good in creating the API which communicates with your existing API.

Comment: Thanks, Naved. I'll take a look at those two. The abstract factory pattern seems to look like a potential candidate, too.

Answer (score 0):

I would say with the adapter or facade. The decorator pattern could also be used. It provides the providers with the ability to add ("decorate") products with additional information.